# How can insert value by selecting from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have three tables. table1 for insert data and table2, table3 for selecting data.

```
table1:
int id,
varchar name,
varchar gender,
varchar category,

table2:
int id,
varchar gender,

table3:
int id,
varchar category,
```

According to these tables, i'm using stored procedure as below:

```
Create procedure ABC
(
@id varchar(10),
@name varchar(11),
@gender varchar(10),
@category varchar(10)
)
As
begin
Insert into table1(id, name, gender, category) select @id, @name, g.id, c.id from gender g, category c where g.gender=@gender and c.category=@category
end
```

Now, using this if gender or category is empty then data is not inserting. Please tell me where i'm wrong and tell best query to insert data using select query. Please help me to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: you want to insert your gender.id in this table now if gender is empty then how can you get this id, what is your expected output.

Comment: Effectively your proc prevents incorrect or missing data to be inserted. If you need to insert data without this kind of sanity check just insert into the table directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `and` in where clause which means only if `gender = @gender` then it is selecting any record.

```
Create procedure ABC
(
@id int,       ----- change this to int since id is int type in your table
@name varchar(11),
@gender varchar(10)='',
@category varchar(10)=''
)
As
begin
Insert into table1(id, name, gender, category) 
select @id, @name, g.id, c.id from gender g, category c 
where (g.gender=@gender or isnull(@gender,'')='') and (c.category=@category or isnull(@category,'')='')
end
```

Although you may use this approach. But since you want to insert id of gender and category column in your table, then on passing `null` or `blank` value what is your expected id to be put in your record.

It is better if you first check gender and category value in your respected table and if record not found then insert it in your table and then save its corresponding id in your final table.